# Why is the EditText (setOutput) not showing the output?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to convert units on taking input from the `EditText` getInput and setting the output to the `EditText` setOutput but the setOutput is not showing the result. I can't understand why.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    final EditText setOutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);

    Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    double factor;


    final String units [] = {
            "Centimeter",
            "Metres",
            "Kilometres",
            "Feet"
    };

    final Spinner unitsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.out);
    final Spinner unitsSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.in);



    ArrayAdapter<String> A = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            units);

    unitsSpinner.setAdapter(A);

    unitsSpinner1.setAdapter(A);



    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            int position = unitsSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            int position2 = unitsSpinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

            double inputValue = Double.valueOf(getInput.getText().toString());

            double outputValue;


            if (position == 0 && position2 == 1){

                outputValue = inputValue * 0.01;

                String output = Double.toString(outputValue);

                setOutput.setText(output);


            }

            if (position == 0 && position2 == 2){

                outputValue = inputValue * 0.001;

                String output = Double.toString(outputValue);

                setOutput.setText(output);


            }

            if (position == 0 && position2 == 3){

                outputValue = inputValue * 0.032;

                String output = Double.toString(outputValue);

                setOutput.setText(output);


            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What is .getSelectedItemPosition() returning for both spinners?

Comment: The units viz. Metre, Centimetre

Comment: I mean, the value that gets into the variables `position` and `position2`. Have you checked if the functions are actually returning the index you think they should return? Add some logging to verify that with logcat.

Comment: Run your app in debug mode. Step through the code, and check that the variables have the values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = unitsSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        int position2 = unitsSpinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

        double outputValue;
        double inputValue = Double.parseDouble(getInput.getText().toString());

        if (position == 0 && position2 == 1){
            outputValue = inputValue * 0.01;
        }

        if (position == 0 && position2 == 2){
            outputValue = inputValue * 0.001;
        }

        if (position == 0 && position2 == 3){
            outputValue = inputValue * 0.032;
        }

        String output = Double.toString(outputValue);
        setOutput.setText(output);

    }
});
```